# Q-Exponential Sum Identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, quantum-calculus

We define the "standard" q-exponential as follows

$$ e_q(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{1} x+ \frac{1}{(1+q)} x^2 + \frac{1}{(1+q)(1+q+q^2)}x^3 ...  =$$

$$ \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \left[ (1-q)^ix^i \prod_{j=1}^{i} \frac{1}{(1-q^j)} \right]$$

What I'm interested in studying is $e_q(x + y)$ inspired by the fact that

$$ e^{(x+y)} = e^{x} e^{y} $$

Is there a known "q-analog" of multiplication this way? What sort of identites exist of

$$ e_q(x+y) ?$$

Comment: I think that the product inside the sum should start at $j= 1$ not $j=0$

Comment: @GuyFsone corrected :)